# Can't set up a HStack with a resizable Image in it

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've been trying to make a view that has an `HStack` with an `Image` in it, the `Image` is set to be resizable with `aspectRatio` of `.fill`. Somehow it ruins all frames and introduces spaces in the layout

[image]

For example, there is an unnecessary margin from the top on the screenshot above. I've tried manually setting frames of Image of HStack, but they are still offset from the top by a margin, even if the height is correct. How do I get rid of it?

Code for the body:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.09019607843, green: 0.09411764706, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1))
        HStack {
            Image("onboardingOrnament").resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
            Spacer()
            VStack() {
                VStack(spacing: 20) {
                    Text("INSTATOOL")
                        .font(.custom("Ubuntu-Medium", size: 28))
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                    Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.")
                        .font(.custom("AvenirNextCyr-Medium", size: 14))
                        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4823529412, green: 0.4980392157, blue: 0.6196078431, alpha: 1)))
                }
                .padding(.top, 100)
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.viewController?.present(style: .fullScreen, transitionStyle: .coverVertical) {
                       DashboardView()
                    }
                }) {
                    ZStack() {
                        HStack() {
                            Text("NEXT")
                            .font(.custom("AvenirNextCyr-Demi", size: 16))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1294117647, green: 0.137254902, blue: 0.1882352941, alpha: 1)))
                            Image("arrowOnboarding")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 14, height: 6)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.1294117647, green: 0.137254902, blue: 0.1882352941, alpha: 1)))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 190, height: 50)

                .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 0.6745098039, blue: 0.1882352941, alpha: 1)))
                .cornerRadius(10)
                Spacer().frame(height: 50)
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to expand out of safe area, like

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.09019607843, green: 0.09411764706, blue: 0.1333333333, alpha: 1))
        HStack {
            Image("test1").resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                // .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height) // << wrong !!

          // ... other content


    }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)    // << this one !!
}
```